# How to remove grid lines from Flot chart

Tags: flot, bar-chart

I am using Flot in my application and it is working fine. I want to remove both vertical lines and horizontal lines from the the background of the chart. I tried this but I am not able to achieve the functionality.

```
grid: {
    verticalLines:false,
    horizontalLines:false
}
```

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You **can** remove the lines, use `tickLength: 0`

```
$.plot("#flot", dataset,
{
    yaxis: {tickLength:0}, 
    xaxis: {tickLength:0}
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tbeap/).

Running demo:

```js
$(function () {

someData = [[1, 3],
            [2, 16],
            [3, 3],
            [4, 3],
            [5, 8],
            [6, 12],
            [7, 3]];
    
var dataset = [
    {color: "#edc240", data: someData, lines: {show: true}, points: {show: true}}    
]; 
    $.plot("#flot", dataset,
    {
        yaxis: {tickLength:0}, 
        xaxis: {tickLength:0}
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<div id="flot" style="width:500px;height:300px;margin:20px"></div>
```

Comment: You __could__ remove the lines! +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

You can paint them the same color as the background.

There is a option called `tickColor` that you have to use for both axis:

```
var options = {
    yaxis: {
        tickColor: "#f00" // or same color as background
    },
    xaxis: {
        tickColor: "#0f0" // or same color as background
    }
};
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WBhLw/)